# React Native 3 button and 3 Modal

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

For example, there are 3 buttons and 3 models how ways to make the model specific to each other?

How are the 3 buttons can bring up model according to the button that is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this one. Edited my code for full version

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, Modal, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      modal1: false,
      modal2: false,
      modal3: false,
    }
  }

  _toggleModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      modal1:false,
      modal2: false,
      modal3: false,
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <SafeAreaView>
        {/*Modal 1*/}
        <Modal
          transparent={true}
          animationType={'none'}
          visible={this.state.modal1}
          onRequestClose={() => {console.log('close modal')}}>
          <View>
           <Text>Modal1</Text>
          </View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({modal1:false})}>
           <Text>Hide Me!</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </Modal>
        {/*Modal 2*/}
        <Modal
          transparent={true}
          animationType={'none'}
          visible={this.state.modal2}
          onRequestClose={() => {console.log('close modal')}}>
          <View>
           <Text>Modal2</Text>
          </View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({modal2:false})}>
           <Text>Hide Me!</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </Modal>
        {/*Modal 3*/}
        <Modal
          transparent={true}
          animationType={'none'}
          visible={this.state.modal3}
          onRequestClose={() => {console.log('close modal')}}>
          <View>
           <Text>Modal3</Text>
          </View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({modal3:false})}>
           <Text>Hide Me!</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </Modal>

        {/*Front Page*/}
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => this.setState({modal1:true})}>
          <Text>Click for Modal 1</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => this.setState({modal2:true})}>
          <Text>Click for Modal 2</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => this.setState({modal3:true})}>
          <Text>Click for Modal 3</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }

}

export default App
```

Comment: yes, but how can i call every modal according to the button ?

Comment: <TouchableOpacity onPress={'modal1'}>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={'modal2'}>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={'modal3'}>

<Modal1></Modal1>
<Modal2></Modal2>
<Modal3></Modal3>

Comment: Try to figure out the function of the buttons. Paste your code on what have you done so far so that i can help take a look at it

Comment: Can you show the this._toggleModal.method? Or if you can show the whole code from class App extends React.Component

Comment: thank u very much sir it's work now, i just typo visible={} it should be isVisible={}

thanks for the logic :))